# Project Euler 24 using java Logical Error

Tags: java, functional-programming, permutation

I am trying to solve problem 24 
https://projecteuler.net/problem=24 
of the project euler and I have spent a lot of time on this problem but still no success.

But now it's not about the problem, I wanted to know what wrong with my method.

I am using simple permutation to get the leftmost digit and getting the remaining value from the term to be found (by subtracting i.e. using modulo operator).

Java Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LexOrder
{

public static int factorial(int num)
{
    int res=1;
    if(num <= 1)
        return 1;

    while(num > 1)  
    {
        res *= num--;   
    }
    return res;
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> addValue(int digit, ArrayList<Integer> al)
{
    int temp=0, count=0;    
    while( count <= digit )
    {
        if( al.contains(count) )
            temp++;
     count++;
    }

    int val = digit+temp;

    //checking weather the new number exists in the ArrayList or not.
    while(true)
    {
        if(! al.contains(val) )
        {
            al.add(val);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            val++;
        }
    }
    return al;
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();   
    int index = 999999; 
    int numOfDigit = 10;

    if( factorial( numOfDigit ) > index && index >= 0)
    {
            System.out.println("Index Validated");
    }
    else
    {
            System.out.println("Index out of bounds");
            System.exit(0);
    }

    int digit, count=1;
    while( index !=0  )
    {
        digit = ( index / factorial( numOfDigit - count ) );
        al = addValue(digit, al);

        index = ( index % factorial( numOfDigit - count ) );

        if(index == 0)
            break;
        count++;
    }

    // Adding value in ascending order.
    int temp =0;
    while( al.size() < numOfDigit )
    {

        if(!al.contains(temp))
            al.add(temp);

    temp++;
    }

    System.out.println(al);
}
}
```

Output:
[2, 7, 8, 3, 9, 1, **4, 5**, 6, 0]

Output should be: 
278391**54**60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So without being able to walk you through the exact numbers I can tell something is off with the way you manage your digits:

```
int temp=0, count=0;    
while( count <= digit )
{
    if( al.contains(count) )
        temp++;
 count++;
}

int val = digit+temp;
```

This approach in particular fails to check whether or not some of the numbers (particularly those between `digit` and `digit+temp`) are already in your array list.

I was able to fix it by counting on the number of elements not used instead:

```
int val=0, count=0;
while( count < digit)
{   if( !al.contains(val++) )
        count++;
}
```

Comment: It works, and it's much better than my answer as it keeps as much of the OP's original code as possible.

Comment: @Linus
Thank You!
God Bless You :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the method `addValue`. A simple but inefficient way of writing this method correctly is

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> addValue(int digit, ArrayList<Integer> al) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9));
    list.removeAll(al);
    al.add(list.get(digit));
    return al;  // Really this should be a void method as al is a parameter.
}
```

With these changes, the output is as you required.

Comment: Actually, my design for the problem would be to keep this list of unused digits from the start and just remove for it as you go (since in this context they are symbols not quantities). So this is only inefficient because it conforms to the existing method header, but it is a very good idea in general.

Comment: @Linus I completely agree. If I was writing it from scratch it would be very different.

Comment: @PaulBoddington
Thank You!
God Bless You :)